# How to add optional arguments to a package I'm writing?

Tags: package-writing, optional-arguments

I want to build a package that can optionally typeset line in double-space.
Something like this:

```
\ProvidePackage{mypackage}
% actual functional codes
```

Then I can use the package in this way:

```
\usepackage[doublespc=yes]{mypackage}
```

So that all line will be typeset in double-space.
If I omit that optional argument in the preamble, then all line will be typeset in single-space.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: That sounds like a class (design) not package (functionality) thing

Comment: Is the keyval part here important, and are you going to have several keyval option? If you only have one, 'faking' keyval may be the easiest approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a basic implementation, following the guide [LaTeX 2e for class and package writers](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf) (section **4.3 Option declaration**, p 18):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents

\begin{filecontents*}{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\newif\if@doublespace
\DeclareOption{doublespace}{\@doublespacetrue}
\ProcessOptions
\if@doublespace\RequirePackage{setspace}\doublespacing\fi
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[doublespace]{mypackage}
\begin{document}
Here is some

text in two paragraphs.
\end{document}
```

The package `mypackage.sty` declares an option `doublespace` which sets the condition `\@doublespacetrue`. If this is set to true, it `\RequiresPackage{setspace}` and sets `\doublespacing`.

Comment: Great! It's exactly what I want. A nice template for optional arguments.