# How to write a piecewise function with equation number?

Tags: labels, cases

I have an equation written in the following way

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
.................

\[
f(x)= \begin{cases}
 e^x, & x\in [-1,1], \\
[x], &  x\notin [-1,1].
\end{cases}
\]
```

However, this leaves the equation with no number. Adding a `\label{test}` does not help. How do I fix that?

Comment: Instead of `\[` and `\]`, use an `equation` environment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f(x)= \begin{cases}
 e^x, & x\in [-1,1], \\
[x], &  x\notin [-1,1].
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}`

Comment: Single equation number? Then see leandris' comment, equation number for each item in the cases, see the similar example in the `empheq` manual.

Comment: To complement daleif's comment, you coud write with `empheq` : `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{empheq} \begin{document} \begin{empheq}[left={f(x) = \empheqlbrace}]{align} e^x, & x\in [-1,1], \\[x], &  x\notin [-1,1].\end{empheq}\end{document}`. And if you want number.letter numbering of each line, you can wrap the `empheq` inside a `subequations` environment after loading the `subequations` package

Comment: Thank you guys - I'm happy to accept any/all of those as an answer if you would like to post them.

Comment: This already has an answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31956/106804

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add optional arguments to a package I'm writing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106804/how-to-add-optional-arguments-to-a-package-im-writing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate labels in cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with the package `witharrows`. In the following example, I have used the option `subequations` in order to have a sub-numerotation of the equations.

As the main goal of `witharrows` was, as its name says, to draw extra arrows, I have added an arrow in the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows}<f(x)=>[format = ll,subequations]
 e^x,\quad & x\in [-1,1], 
\Arrow[tikz=-]{two cases} \\
[x], &  x\notin [-1,1].
\end{DispWithArrows}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]