# How do I merge different .sty files?

Tags: packages, multiple-files

I have multiple small .sty files like 'layout.sty' or 'table.sty' and I want to create one 'main.sty' file that summarizes everything.

Optionally I would like to have the ability of passing down packages from the 'main.sty' file to all sub-files included thereafter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please clarify what "merge" and "summarizes everything" is supposed to denote in the present context. E.g., are looking to combine all existing style files in a single new file called `main.sty`, or are you trying to create a file called `main.sty` that  loads a bunch of other style files?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106804/how-to-add-optional-arguments-to-a-package-im-writing.